# How to make a matrix from a specific dataframe format in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I have a dataframe with the following format

```
query <- rep(c("Hallo1", "Hallo2", "Hallo3", "Hallo4"), each = 4)
reference <- rep(c("Hallo1", "Hallo2", "Hallo3", "Hallo4"), 4)
cor_value <- c(100,78,97,87,78,100,89,84,97,89,100,72,87,84,72,100)
demo_table <- data.frame(query, reference, cor_value)
demo_table
```

From that data-frame I want to retrieve a matrix square matrix, this is the desired output:

|  | Hallo1 | Hallo2 | Hallo3 | Hallo4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hallo1 | 100 | 78 | 97 | 87 |
| Hallo2 | 78 | 100 | 89 | 84 |
| Hallo3 | 97 | 89 | 100 | 72 |
| Hallo4 | 87 | 84 | 72 | 100 |

I want to achieve this in R, I tried with pivot_wider() but I don't know if this is the correct function in my case.

Comment: `xtabs(rev(demo_table))`

Answer (score 1):

`pivot_wider` is the correct first step however, you need to then turn `query` column to rownames of the matrix to get the desired output.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

demo_table %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = reference, values_from = cor_value) %>%
  column_to_rownames("query") %>%
  as.matrix()

#       Hallo1 Hallo2 Hallo3 Hallo4
#Hallo1    100     78     97     87
#Hallo2     78    100     89     84
#Hallo3     97     89    100     72
#Hallo4     87     84     72    100
```

Comment: Thanks so much! , I provided a demo data but now I'm encountering another problem, seems like pivot_wider doesn't accept values that are almost equal. I got a warning message "values from cor_value are not uniquely identified". and the output matrix is empty but with the correct dimensions that I desired. maybe I should open another issue but I have a value of 100 (one value of the diagonal) and another cell of 99.9965 which is approximated to 100 by default in R. This happens for more than 2 values on my data.